# Prevent jQuery autocomplete from filtering data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I've got a jQuery control derived from [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) but with a remote data source returning a JSON object.  The server method that filters the results is somewhat advanced, searching within the second line of description text as well as the main one.  I want all the data returned displayed, regardless of whether the typed search term appears in the main label.  Can I force jQuery to not filter the results and to rely on my server method to return only the relevant ones?

Comment: What exactly does your code look like? Specifically, are you using a local or remote data source?

Comment: Turns out there wasn't a problem at all and I was just being thick.  Thanks anyway.